# Prove that closed interval is not open

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

"Prove that the set $A=[a,b)$ is not open." I am looking for a rigorous proof.

My approach:

Suppose that $A$ is actually open, which, by definition, would mean that for any $x\in A$ there would exist some $\epsilon>0$ such that the neighbourhood of $x$: $N_\epsilon(x)=(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subseteq A$.

Choose $x=a$, then we have $N_\epsilon(a)=(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$. Now, we find a point $\xi \in N_\epsilon(a)$ such that $\xi\notin A$. For all $\xi\in N_\epsilon(a)$ we have $a-\epsilon<\xi<a+\epsilon$. We choose $\xi=a-\epsilon/2$ therefore we have $a-\epsilon<\xi<a<a+\epsilon$. By definition of  interval, $A=\{x|x\geq a \wedge x<b\}$. That shows that $\xi\notin A$ therefore $N_\epsilon(a)\not\subseteq A$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

My question is: Is this proof valid and rigorous enough? Can it be made simpler?

Comment: Your proof is valid, and it's the simplest proof I would imagine.

Comment: Well done, precise and concise

Comment: If we wanted to show that the interval is also not closed, would it be okay to show that $ \mathbb{R} \setminus [a,b)$ is not open in the same way, or is there a cleaner way to do so? (Given that the interval is defined on $\mathbb{R}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks very good. I would recommend a slight adjustment, though. You say the following:

> For all $\xi\in N_\epsilon(a)$ we have $a-\epsilon<\xi<a+\epsilon$.

This is true, but not used in your proof. Rather, you use the *converse* of this statement, so I'd say the following, instead:

> For all $\xi$ such that $a-\epsilon<\xi<a+\epsilon,$ we have $\xi\in N_\epsilon(a).$

Then, you have by $a-\epsilon<\xi<a<a+\epsilon$ that $\xi\in N_\epsilon(a)$ and $\xi\notin A,$ by reasoning as you did from there.

---

Aside from the observation above, there is one more issue that should be clarified for rigor: it isn't clear where the $\epsilon$ comes from in "...then we have $N_\epsilon(a)=(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon).$" It *seems* that you were going for a proof by contradiction, so you probably meant something like this:

> ...then since $a\in A,$ we have $N_\epsilon(a)\subseteq A$ for some $\epsilon>0$ by our assumption that $A$ is open.

From there with those few tweaks, since you later prove that $N_\epsilon(a)\nsubseteq A,$ you'll have completed a proof by contradiction. However, you didn't actually need to proceed that way, as you're very close to a *direct* proof that $A$ is not open, by demonstrating that there is an $x\in A$ such that for all $\epsilon>0,$ we have $N_\epsilon(x):=(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\nsubseteq A.$ This is because "$A$ is not open" is the formal negation of "$A$ is open," which looks like any of the following equivalent formal statements: $$\neg\bigl(\forall x\in A, \exists\epsilon>0:N_\epsilon(x)\subseteq A\bigr)\\\exists x\in A:\forall \epsilon>0, \neg\bigl(N_\epsilon(x)\subseteq A\bigr)\\\exists x\in A:\forall \epsilon>0, N_\epsilon(x)\nsubseteq A.$$ If you go the *direct* route, then instead, you'd want to start something like this:

> Take any $\epsilon>0$ and consider $N_\epsilon(a):=(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon).$ We show that $N_\epsilon(a)\nsubseteq A,$ which, since $a\in A,$ will show that $A$ is not open. To do so, we will find a point $\xi\in N_\epsilon(a)$ such that $\xi\notin A.$

From there, you can proceed in much the same way, with the minor tweak I suggested above.

Comment: Wait, you are saying I didn't have to proceed by contradiction but I had done a proof by contrapositive. I'm confused. Also, about that you wrote in the first part of your answer. Aren't these two statemens actually equivalent?
$$\xi\in N_\epsilon(a) \Leftrightarrow a-\epsilon<\xi <a+\epsilon$$
therefore it doesnt matter whether i say it in the way $\Leftarrow$ or $\Rightarrow$

Comment: As far as your confusion about contradiction versus contrapositive: are you confused about the difference between the two, or perhaps unfamiliar with one or the other? As for the first part of my answer: it is certainly true that the statements are equivalent. However, you only stated the implication that you *didn't* use, which is bad form in a rigorous proof, as it relies on the reader to know something beyond the reasoning provided. I'd recommend that you either state the equivalence, or just state the implication that you actually use.

Comment: Well, I know very well what a contrapositive is. Proving a conditional $a\Rightarrow b$ i prove $\neg b\Rightarrow \neg a$ but if i proceeded by contradiction, i would disprove $\neg (a\Rightarrow b) \Leftrightarrow (a\wedge \neg b)$. I understand the part with the equivalence now.

Comment: Good deal! I just noticed another finicky bit. I will adjust my answer presently.

Comment: As I was editing my answer, I figured out what was probably confusing you about my reference to proof by contrapositive: that it really wasn't one! I've made changes accordingly. Let me know if you have any more questions about my answer. :-)

Comment: Now everything seems clear, thanks for analyzing my proof!